# How to pass a date value from view to controller's action using json ajax

Tags: json, ajax, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first

I've been struggling hard to grab a date value from view and save it into the database as `DateTime` Type using JSON AJAX, but it is always saving as a null value,in other words, when it reaches the controller's postback action, the datetime i.e. PurchaseDate value is null, Ok, Let me place a breakpoint there :

[image]

Note that, In the above image Purchase_date is null, whereas, if I `console.log()` the salesmain object at the client side before the ajax request, it contains the grabbed valued from the textbox, lets `console.log(salesmain)` :

[image]

So, Purchase date is a string grabbed from a textbox :

```
<label>Purchase Date :</label>
@Html.TextBox("PurchaseDate")
```

Here is my ajax request :

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/Sales/Create',
        headers: headers,
        data: JSON.stringify(salesmain),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType : 'application/json',
        traditional : true,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.Success == "1") {
                //alert("saved Successfully!");
            }
            else {
                alert(result.ex);
            }
        }
    });
```

In the above code salesmain in a json object that contains the data that is going to be saved in two tables in the database simultaneously, having a one-to-many relationship :

```
{ "SalesId": "", "SystemCode": "", "ReferenceNo": "", "SalesDate": "", "SalesPerson": "", "SalesSubs": [] }
```

In the above JSON object SalesSub array is the **many** part and this SalesSub contains the Purchase_date value :

```
{ "ItemName": "", "Qty": "", "UnitPrice": "", "PurchaseDate": "", "SalesId": "", "SystemCode": "" }
```

This one-to-many structure have the following model, this is SalesMain.cs :

```
public class SalesMain
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public string SalesId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public string SystemCode { get; set; }

    public string ReferenceNo { get; set; }
    public DateTime SalesDate { get; set; }
    public string SalesPerson { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SalesSub> SalesSubs { get; set; }
}
```

and the corresponding **many** relation with SalesSub.cs :

```
[Key]
    public int SalesSubId { get; set; }

    public string ItemName { get; set; }

    public int Qty { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Purchase_date { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SalesMain"), Column(Order = 0)]
    public string SalesId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SalesMain"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public string SystemCode { get; set; }

    public virtual SalesMain SalesMain { get; set; }
```

Note that Purchase_date is of type `DateTime?` and I'm getting a value as string from the textbox, `string != DateTime?` then it may be a model binder issue? If yes, then what should I do to make it work?,every value in the above two models is binding nice and fine except the Purchase_date value, which is always having a null value after postback. What should I do so that the `Purchase_date` contains a values at the `[HttpPost]` Create action rather that a `null` value? Any Help will be deeply appreciated, Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client side code is posting a field with name `PurchaseDate` and your `SalesSub` class's property name is `Purchase_date`. Model binder will work only when both matches.

Change your view model property name to `PurchaseDate` and it will work. Model binder will be able to map a valid string of date time to a `DateTime?` instance.